# How do I test that a 301 redirect takes place with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I need to test two things:

1. that certain old paths are correctly redirected to certain new paths
2. that the redirect is a 301, not a 302.

I'm using Capybara for my acceptance tests, but that can't handle #2. I can test that the redirect happens, but it happens silently, so I can't see that it was a 301.

Controller tests can't handle #1. The "get", "post" etc. verbs that rspec provides for controller tests only allow you to pass in an action, not a specific path, and the redirect is implemented in a single action based on the path, as below:

```
# controller
class ExampleController
  def redirect301
    redirect_to case request.path
    when '/old_a'
      '/new_a'
    when '/old_b'
      '/new_b'
    end, :status => 301
  end
end

# routes.rb
['old_a', 'old_b'].each do |p| 
  map.connect p, :controller => :example, :action => :redirect301
end
```

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
it "should redirect with 301" do
  get :action
  response.code.should == 301
end
```

Comment: OK, that tests that the action exists and returns a 301, but this would still pass if "old_a" got redirected to "new_b" and vice versa.

Comment: so do you need to check redirect status or redirection url?

Comment: then check for response.location value. It will have domain + path. Or response.fullpath for only path part (rails 3 only).

Comment: The correct response varies depending on the contents of the url though (see my code snippet), and I can't change that if "get" only lets me define an action.

Answer (score 1):

To test response status do this - `expect(response.status).to eq(301)`
And to test response url do this - `expect(response.location).to eq(my_path)`

So altogether it should look like this:

```
it "should redirect with a 301 status code to my_path" do
  get :action
  expect(response.status).to eq(301)
  expect(response.location).to eq(my_path)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rspec-rails 2.12.0 and the modern `expect` syntax, this is the correct format:

```
  it "should redirect with a 301 status code to /whatever_path" do
    get :some_action
    expect(response).to redirect_to '/whatever_path' # or a path helper
    expect(response.code).to eq '301'
  end
```

**Notice the string 301** - when I ran this spec with an integer, it failed, comparing 301 against "301" which in Ruby are not equal.